# Image in post not responsive

Tags: wordpress

When a post an image in the middle of the text they were not responsive.
here is the link:
https://gostork.com/blog/posts/welcome-to-our-new-blog/

How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us, and edit your question to include the relevant code in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and details of what you have tried already, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add custom css (for example in Theme Customizer) so to set a max width for your images. They will fit the parent Element using:

`img { max-width: 100% !important; }`

I added the important rule to make sure this is not overwritten elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you want to target images added from the media library with size "large" option selected.

```
img.size-large {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```